# Multithread, Interface, extended interface, in object oriented fashion tracking with Java not working. How can i solve it?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, instance

My question is why or how i can make "listenerList" value as 1 or 2, so that i can track and get status of that instance from alert class with the help of vector()? ex: listenerList is my process id to track them, but its always value of 0

Here is whole code, not working to see the output: "it WORKS!!!, if i can reach here!!!":

**[updated after suggestion, but still same, not working]**

1) Interface

```
public interface Listener
{
    public void registered();
    public void connected(String IP,int Port);
    public void disconnected();
}
```

2) Interface extending

```
public class alert implements Listener
{
  public void  registered() 
  {System.out.println("it WORKS!!!, if i can reach here!!!"); System.exit(0);}
  public void connected(String IP, int Port) 
  { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");}
  public void disconnected() 
  {  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");   }
}
```

3) Main class to use

```
public class Provider extends Thread
{
  public Vector listenerList;
  public alert  alert;   

  public Provider(String userName) throws Exception{ listenerList = new Vector();   
    addListener(alert);
  }
  public void addListener(Listener ls)    {     listenerList.addElement(ls);}  
  public void removeListener(Listener ls) { listenerList.removeElement(ls); }  

  public void run()
  {
    while(running)
    {
      fireRegisteredEvent(); // shows now value of 1, but does not do exit(0);
    }
  }  

  private void fireRegisteredEvent() 
  {
      System.out.println("Fireing Registration: " + System.currentTimeMillis()); 
      System.out.println("Fireing Registration: " + listenerList.size());

      for (int i = 0; i < listenerList.size(); i++) 
      {              
          alert.registered();  
          System.exit(0);                  
      }

  }  
}
```

4) Action

```
private Provider multiinstance;
multiinstance = new Provider("Why are you not triggering: System.exit(0);??????");
multiinstance.start();
```

5) Output

```
Fireing Registration: 1303646370073
Fireing Registration: 1
```

....

6) Expecting result:

```
a) output: System.out.println("it WORKS!!!, if i can reach here!!!");
OR
b) listenerList.size() value is either 1 or 2?!!
OR
c) alert class and interface should react? no?? if not how i can ??
```

Comment: In a comment in your code, it says " // Now on this fire, i am expecting listenerList already have value".. Can you provide us with the code that actually adds the listeners to the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never instantiated a listener and assigned it to one of the providers. In other words you never call `addListener(...)` and thus no listener can be triggered.

Comment: OK, but still not working the output does not come from alert class nor it triggers exit. ex: added public alert alert; addListener(alert);  private void fireRegisteredEvent() { alert.registered(); }  does not still trigger System.exit(0); ?

Comment: Where did you add this code? Did you instantiate alert correctly?

Comment: Please see above my updates. Still same according to your advise.

Comment: @IamSonOfRaja I can only see that you added a `null` to your listener. This will most probably result in a NPE.

Comment: Works from my main central as multiinstance.Listener((Listener) this);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a breakpoint in the while(running) to see if the list has values? It appears the problem is there in the "somehow". Do you actually have a Listener adding values?

Comment: My post is updated. But still not working. while(running) { // has no issue, its optimized in real code, i just draw here the less codes }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (among others) that you never instantiated alert (thereby adding a null reference to the vector). You could for example change the line

```
public alert  alert;
```

to

```
public alert alert = new alert();
```

Also, I recommend reading about Java naming conventions:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html